# Class specialization for array NTTP

Tags: c++, templates, non-type-template-parameter

I'm trying to specialize the template `X` for an array NTTP.

But this does not work:

```
template<auto& V>
struct X {
    static inline auto v = V[0];
};

template<typename T, auto N>
struct X<T (&a)[N] > {
    static inline auto v = N;
};

int main () {
    int ar[10];
    X<ar> x;
    return x.v;
}
```

Is that possible in the first place?
Or should one use requirements / constraints for that purpose?

The errors are:

```
<source>:14:14: error: 'a' was not declared in this scope
   14 | struct X<T (&a)[N] > {
      |              ^
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:20:9: error: the address of 'ar' is not a valid template argument because it does not have static storage duration
   20 |     X<ar> x;
      |         ^
<source>:21:14: error: request for member 'v' in 'x', which is of non-class type 'int'
   21 |     return x.v;
      |              ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Specialization aside, `int ar[10]; X<ar> x;` won't work either way. The template argument must reference a static storage duration array. A type can obviously not depend on the address of a local variable. What is your use case for this construct?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Note that you can get the size of an array with [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Comment: @user17732522 Sure, I corrected the example code.

Comment: @Nelfeal I want to add a specialization for an array-type reference NTTP.

Comment: @wimalopaan I don't see anything changed.

Comment: when you change the code you should make sure that the error message still matches the code. Though, changing the code after you recieved an answer is not nice. (I assume there was overlap between your edit and me posting the answer, so nevermind)

Comment: @wimalopaan That's not what you want to achieve. That's how you think you can achieve it. See also: the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "typo" in the way to specialize (what is `a`)?

The specialization should look like:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, T (&a)[N]>
struct X<a> {
    static inline auto v = N;
};
```

And `ar` should have the appropriate storage duration, as the error further indicates.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zszc9Yn51)

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you cannot use `ar` as template argument because `it does not have static storage duration`. This is one issue.

Then you have a typo in the specialization (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77332096/4117728)). However, consider whether you need to specialize at all. There is `std::is_array` and, as mentioned in a comment, `std::size` to deduce the size:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

#include <array>

template<auto& V>
struct X {
    static inline auto v = std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(V)>> ? std::size(V) : V[0];
};

static constexpr int ar[10]{};

int main () {
    X<ar> x;
    std::cout << X<ar>::v;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7W5Pon3q9)

Comment: *"I didn't manage to get the specialization working"* See my answer.

Comment: @Jarod42 I got confused about the array reference and just blindly copied the typo from OPs code :D

Comment: It's a global variable, what do you mean it doesn't have static storage duration? The compiler is totally wrong on that front.

Comment: because OP edited the code after this answer was posted. And they didnt fix the error message in their post. And they didnt react on my comment when I tried to explain the issue. And I didnt decide yet whether to rollback their edit or to reword the answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica as the question in its current state reports the wrong error I go for a rollback

Comment: Ok, but do note that the solution you propose *requires* constexpr-ness, while the OP's approache doesn't. It's no small difference.